# In Python, displaying an image with openCV and creating a separate window with Tkinter causes crash

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to use a Python script to do two things:

For all image/image caption pairs:

- Display the image, via `cv2.imshow(...)`
- Display the image caption in a window that can be edited, via tkinter `tk.Text(self.root)`

However, this causes a crash. Or at least...it *usually* causes it to crash (it outputs a bunch of bizarre errors then python [or ipython, depending on which I'm using] exits). These errors are of the form:

```
Python[50566:37729544] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb960319cc0'
```

I can abolish these errors if I don't display the image with openCV. I suspect it's something to do with an interaction between `cv2.imshow` and Tk, or how poorly my Tk code was written, but even this ridiculously hacky job took an *enormously* long time to produce. I'm not sure if it's because I'm an idiot, but the Tk documentation seems hugely complex (even simple questions with respect to Tk seem to have answers of the form: "of course you can do that! but it is utterly impossible to give you a quick answer; first, you must peruse the labyrinthine documentation on the vagaries of how to do callbacks and switchforths and jargon and words I've never heard before and such with Tk. Have fun!").

The code that produces the window for the editable caption is this. And I'm sure it violates any number of tenets when it comes to using Tk:

```
class editcap():
    # allows editing of the captions
    def __init__(self, caption):
        self.precap = caption
    def get(self):
        self.caption = self.text.get("1.0",tk.END)
        self.root.destroy()
    def getesc(self, event):
        self.caption = event.widget.get("1.0",tk.END)
        self.root.destroy()
    def disp(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() # it crashes here 
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.text.insert(tk.INSERT, self.precap)
        self.text.pack()
        submit = tk.Button(self.root, text ="Submit", command = self.get)
        submit.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
        self.text.bind('<Escape>', self.getesc)
        self.root.mainloop()
        return self.caption
```

Displaying images via opencv

```
def display_img(post):
    img = get_image(post) # saves the image from web if it hasn't already been saved, load via plt.imread()
    if resample_to != None:
        wxr = resample_to * 1. / img.shape[1]
        hx = img.shape[0] * wxr
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR), (resample_to, int(hx)))
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Comment: Can you show the OpenCV code too?

Comment: Try adding `cv2.waitKey(1)` (wait 1 millisecond for a keypress, i.e. don't wait at all) or `cv2.waitKey(0)` (wait forever for a key press) after the line `cv2.imshow(...)`.

Comment: I suspect that's not the problem. It pauses either way via `rawinput()` -- which cases it to draw the image properly. It only attempts to edit the caption if I request as much, which occurs many hundreds possibly thousands of milliseconds after it has been drawn to the screen. But I'll try it anyway!

Comment: yeah, alas it did not work :-(

Comment: ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?